# rearraging converstaions with lastest on top in php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

we have building a chat application using php and mysql and our table structure looks like this

`converstation_table_name`

```
id
conversation_id
created_at
user_1
user_2
```

`messages`

```
sender
reciever
message
created_at
conversation_id
```

here are the values in both tables

`conversation_table_name`

```
id | con_id(shortname) | created_at | user_1 | user_2 |
 1 | 123132            |   now      |   1    |    5   |
 2 | 123133            |   now      |   1    |    3   |
 3 | 123134            |   now      |   1    |    4   |
 4 | 123135            |   now      |   1    |    2   |
```

`messages`

```
sender | reciever | message | created_at | conversation_id |
     1 |    3     |   abc   |   now      |     123133      |
     3 |    1     |   cee   |   now      |     123133      |
     1 |    2     |   1411  |   now      |     123135      |
     1 |    5     |   1-5   |   now      |     123132      |
```

now we want to arrange the output something like this

```
123132
between 1 - 5
123135
between 1 - 2
123133
between 1 - 3
```

how to go about it, in short we want to make the latest message in user conversation to appear on top, just like facebook does with it's messaging system, how to go about it, we are still looking for a working answer

Comment: Use order by created_at DESC in your query.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 can you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to show the inserted data back to user you can simply use created_at field to fetch data in descending order and display it.

Comment: select * from messages order by created_at DESC; and you can join other tables to fetch more data for this message; :)

Comment: Does your `created_at` column actually contain the word `now` or does it contain a `datetime` value that you filled with the MYSQL function `NOW()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly too lazy to type the current timestamp

Comment: Ditto: To lasy to answer a question from someone thats to lazy to ask a complete and accurate question!

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

Can be introduced new field viewed or seen with datetime field. On visiting message update the field. So can be used order by that field and you will have the viewed time.